# Laravel route model binding using custom key not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm attempting to modify the route key for a specific API route in my application:

```
Route::get('/profiles/{userProfile:username}', function (UserProfile $userProfile) {
    return $userProfile;
});
```

However, when I access `{{base_url}}/profiles/user-349`, I encounter the following error:

```
"No query results for model [App\\Models\\UserProfile] user-349"
```

Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Here is my table proof that the record existed.

[image]

Note:

I opted not to employ the `getRouteKeyName()` method in the model. Instead, I chose to model bind all routes, except for this particular one, which utilizes the custom key `username`.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256902/discussion-on-question-by-draw134-laravel-route-model-binding-using-custom-key-n); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe This Code Help You :

```
Route::get('/profiles/{username}', function (\App\Models\UserProfile $username) {
    return $username;
});
```

Comment: i think that is not how model binding works when using custom key. but thanks for the help sir